# Phrases with the word "progress"

Tags: phrase-request, idioms

I study English as a second language, and noticed that some collocations in my native language and English can differ.

I'm writing an essay and I want to translate one phrase into English correctly. Literally it is

> Progress doesn't stay in one place.

Do native speakers say this?
What words should I change in the phrase?
Or you have your own equivalent?

Comment: for better understanding: I mean that every century saw new technological advances

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with your phrase

> Progress doesn't stay in one place.

it is understandable and grammatically correct.  Metaphorically it has implied "movement" which is characteristic of progress.  All native speakers would understand it.

An alternative with similar meaning might be

> Progress doesn't stand still.

Comment: Thank you a lot) It seems to be the equivalent to the phrase in my native language)

Answer (score 4):

You  may use a common [expression](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=you%20can%27t%20stop%20progress&year_start=1900&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cyou%20can%20not%20stop%20progress%3B%2Cc0) which I think is close to the meaning you want to suggest:

> You can't stop progress

Comment: Also things and events can be shaped by the *wheels of progress*, generally considered to be beyond individual control.

Answer (score 2):

There aren't really any proverbs specifically about progress. The nearest that I can suggest is

> Time and tide wait for no man [Cambridge Dictionary](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/time-and-tide-wait-for-no-man)

If this isn't what you are looking for, you could try [here](http://www.special-dictionary.com/proverbs/keywords/change/2.htm)